# How to sync variable with async callback in node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have doubt in following code snippet.

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
    http.request(option, function(res){
        console.log(i)
    });
}
```

This prints value of 'i' as 5, five times. Is there any way to make value of 'i' in sync with function(res) which can print 0,1,2,3,4

Comment: Oh, classic problem. Wrap in an IIFE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give the variables the correct scope. Try something like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
    (function(key) {
        http.request(option, function(res){
            console.log(key)
        });
    })(i);
}
```